# Regex which accepts alphanumerics only, except for one hyphen in the middle

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to construct a regular expression which accepts alphanumerics only (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`), except for a single hyphen (`-`) in the middle of the string, with a minimum of 9 characters and a maximum of 20 characters.

I have verified the following expression, which accepts a hyphen in the middle.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\-?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

How can I set the minimum 9 and maximum 20 characters for the above regex? I have already used quantifiers `+` and `?` in the above expression.

How would I apply `{9,20}` to the above expression? Are there any other suggestions for the expression?

Comment: I don't think this is something that can be done completely with a regular expression. It'd be easier to match the pattern and then check the overall length afterwards (or beforehand).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this provided you don't want `-` to be present exactly in middle

```
 /^(?=[^-]+-?[^-]+$)[a-zA-Z\d-]{9,20}$/
```

`[^-]` matches any character that is not `-`

Comment: Why are you using `{10,21}` to check for 9 to 20 chars?

Comment: Anirudh, I don't want the hyphen to be exactly in the middle. Its an optional character in the string and should not be counted for length of the string. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I think @kranthi meant that the whole string (including the dash) should be 9 to 20.

Comment: @BrianStephens you are right brian..i have edited the ans..thx

Comment: I mean following strings are valid:
abcd12345 is valid.
abcd-1234 is not valid

Comment: This pattern fails on the case where the string is 20 alphanumerics and a hyphen (putting the total up to 21 chars), which according to @kranthip 's requirements should be valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\-?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

can be simplified to

```
/^[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)?$/i
```

since if there is no dash then you don't need to look for more letters after it, and you can use the `i` flag to match case-insensitively and avoid having to reiterate both lower-case and upper-case letters.

Then split your problem into two cases:

1. 9-20 alpha numerics
2. 10-21 characters, all of which are alpha numerics except one dash

You can check the second using a positive lookahead like

```
/^(?=.{10,21}$)/i
```

to check the number of characters without consuming them.

Combining these together gives you

```
/^(?:[a-z0-9]{9,20}|(?=.{10,21}$)[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+)$/i
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is the lookahead meant for checking the length proceeding expression? Can we ignore the hyphen while counting the number of characters in the string ?