# Using regex in Nodejs stopping flow

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm experimenting with a regex from another question: [Regex which accepts alphanumerics only, except for one hyphen in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599508/regex-which-accepts-alphanumerics-only-except-for-one-hyphen-in-the-middle)

I have this code as part of my validation of a username:

```
...
var re = /^(?:[a-z0-9]{6,20}|(?=.{10,21}$)[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+)$/i;
var found = username.match(re).length;
...
```

but the flow stops here and won't continue past this point if the username is invalid. I need to be able to ask:

```
if(username fails regex) {
  send error back to client
}
```

Comment: Is this a validation handler? Shouldn't it transparently do the work? Or, if match() return true, else false.

Comment: yes it's a validation handler

Comment: I'm not sure how to construct the condition using a regex. If someone adds an answer I can give it a go.

Comment: Just drop `.length`, this way `found` will have either `null` or `[username]`. Then `if (!found) { throw "error"; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `str.match(regex)` is that it will return `null` if no match is found, consider this:

```
console.log('hello'.match(/world/)); // null
```

And reading `.length` from `null` will throw a TypeError.

You should try using `regex.test(str)` which will return a boolean:

```
var re = /^(?:[a-z0-9]{6,20}|(?=.{10,21}$)[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+)$/i;
var found = re.test(username); // true or false
```